# mysql - set foreign key constraint on Id column and INSERT Max value in 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to set up a constraint so that when INSERT a record into the `Item` table - a record is inserted into the `itemIndustryCodesLookup` assignment table.

Is this possible in MySql (InnoDB) Database?

How would I go about setting it up?

This is the insert I would like to be able to make for example. `itemPrice` can be null because it defaults to 0.00, I want `itemIndustryCodesLookupId` to actually be the next available `itemIndustryCodesLookupId` value in the `itemIndustryCodesLookup` table. Column `isEnabled` is a Bit column and has a default value of 0.

```
INSERT INTO `nextcart`.`item`
(`itemId`,
`itemName`,
`itemSku`,
`itemPrice`,
`itemIndustryCodesLookupId`,
`isEnabled`)
VALUES
(
NULL,
'Max Extract All-Terrain Carpet Washer',
'F7452900',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL
);
```

This is the Alter Statement I ran on the `Item` table.

```
ALTER TABLE `item` ADD CONSTRAINT industry_codes_refs FOREIGN KEY (`itemIndustryCodesLookupId`) REFERENCES `itemindustrycodeslookup` (`itemIndustryCodesLookupId`);
```

This is the error I get: 
    Error Code: 1048. Column 'itemIndustryCodesLookupId' cannot be null

I guess my alternative question is, am I setting this up correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). There you can specify the query that will execute once row is inserted to the first table

Comment: Thanks for the link and fast advice! I looked and saw I will execute a trigger BEFORE INSERT. Both answers came in at the same time, but yours had the link I needed. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

1) "I am trying to set up a constraint so that when INSERT a record into the Item table - a record is inserted into a second assignment table.

Is this possible in MySql (InnoDB) Database?"

To achieve that functionality you must use triggers.

2) You con't use column which contains NULL-s as foreign key which tells you error.